# Spyder: No linebreaks in ipython console output

Tags: python, spyder

I am trying to set up Spyder to behave more like RStudio, where every line of output is displayed on the Ipython console. I've managed to set up things with the options below, but it is resulting in odd line breaks (circled in red).

Any way to fix this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IULqd.png)

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

pd.options.display.width = 1000

from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"

titanic = pd.read_csv("c:/users/zsg876/titanic.csv")

#titanic.loc[titanic["Age"]>35,"Name"] #When using names use LOC
#titanic.iloc[9:25, 2:5] #when indexing use ILOC


titanic[["Sex", "Age"]].groupby("Sex").mean()

titanic
```

Comment: that looks like an error with the data in the dataframe.  can you please provide the data as part of the code.

Comment: Sure, it's available here: https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs109/cs109.1166/stuff/titanic.csv

I don't think the issue is the dataset, just the formatting of the output.

Comment: thanks for the data, I have seen this type of problem before.  solved.  see the answer...

Answer (score 0):

I get the same in `vscode`.
it is not the ide, but infact the way the `groupby operates. so i added` reset_index` and it works.

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

pd.options.display.width = 1000

from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"

titanic = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\admin\\Downloads\\titanic.csv")

#titanic.loc[titanic["Age"]>35,"Name"] #When using names use LOC
#titanic.iloc[9:25, 2:5] #when indexing use ILOC


x=titanic[["Sex", "Age"]].groupby("Sex").mean().reset_index()
print(x)
```

This was the output with the original code:

```
              Age
Sex
female  27.719745
male    30.431361
```

This is the output with the updated code:

```
      Sex        Age
0  female  27.719745
1    male  30.431361
```

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. If you run the full script and have it output into the console, you'll notice the command for `mean' and `titanic' are produced but run together. It would be ideal if there was a linebreak visually separating the two so one could read the output more easily. Did you click on the image I linked and see the red circle?

Comment: i thought that you were referring to the `age` being on the incorrect line, which was also in the red circle on the image provided!!    The other might simply be resolved be adding a empty line `print()`...

Comment: Right but I don't want to add that for every command. Imagine I run several different commands, this would be a huge pain and seems like an issue with formatting the console output?

Comment: i agreed with you.  i have used `spyder` (it was my first ide for python) and ended up switching to `vscode` for similar reasons...